# "Freeze" iframes with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have a web application that has a handful of iframes on it, some of which are hidden from view at any given time. The user can choose which iframes are visible with controls on the page.

Right now, I'm accomplishing this by setting the "unselected" iframes' style settings to `display: none`, and this accomplishes what I want, but I was hoping to get an extra benefit out of it - these iframes have Javascript running in them. When they're not visible, there isn't any benefit to using computer resources to let that Javascript run.

Is there any way I can "freeze" an iframe, i.e. pause JS execution? My Google searches haven't turned up anything yet, so I'm not expecting it, but if there is such a way it would be a nice performance win.

Thank you!

Comment: Well if nothing is *happening* to them, no JS will be executed in them, you don't have any long-running scripts or active communication in them, do you?

Comment: Why  not just remove them entirely from your page instead of only hiding them?

Comment: in short, you're google is correct: "no, there's not a way to do that"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use event.preventDefault() on common events like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("iframe").onclick = function(event) {
    return false;
  };
</script>
```

As far as I know you cannot capture events in iFrames, but you could include this in the html of the iframe.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // don't forget all the other events you would like to stop
  toStop = ["click", "mousemove", "keypress"]
  for(var i = 0; i < toStop.length; i++) {
    iframe = document.getElementById("your-target-iframe");
    iframe.addEventListener(toStop[i], function(event) {
      return false;
    }, false);
  }
</script>
```

In jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // don't forget all the other events you would like to stop
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $.each(["click", "mousemove", "keypress"], function(index, eventToStop) {
      $("#your-target-iframe").on(eventToStop, function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

NOTE: these are some "hacky" ways to go about this problem and please keep in mind that your Google search was correct and that there are no standard ways to do this.